# Flask handle uploaded csv on the fly by csv module

Tags: python, csv, flask, file-upload, request

Simply, I need to work with files uploaded without saving it on server

working in cli script using `open()` every thing is fine,

---

using flask with file sent from data by ajax request
neither `open()` function nor `stream.read()` method helped to work with the csv

open throws an exception itself

```py
csv_f = open(request.files['csvfile'].stream, 'rb')
```

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not SpooledTemporaryFile
```

---

using `.read()` I can print it

```py
csv_f = request.files['csvfile'].stream.read()
data = csv.reader(csv_f, delimiter = ',')

print(csv_f)
```

```
b'...'
```

but Iterating also throws exception

```
for row in data:
```

```
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

---

#### I need only a way to work with csv files using `csv` module on the fly

Comment: where do you fetch your file from (S3 bucket, hadoop, remote server...) ?

Comment: form data by ajax request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - writing and reading from a temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983886/python-writing-and-reading-from-a-temporary-file)

Comment: `open()` doesn't open file from flask `request` object

Comment: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not SpooledTemporaryFile`

Comment: it's a helpful link but doesn't help with my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem

the file is going throw request as a binary stream not a normal text

that's why it has a read method but unuseful when itrating

I had to use `.decode()`
like this

```py
request.files['csvfile'].stream.read().decode("utf-8")
```

instead of this
`request.files['csvfile'].stream.read()`